# How optimize this distance query based on latitude and longitude in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database of UK postcodes with latitude and longitude values. I have a query that allows me to pass in a number in miles, the lat and lng values and it will find all rows within a radius of the passed in miles. This works but the query is very slow.

There are 1 778 632 rows in the table and I have added indexes to all the columns but it does not make any difference to the execution speed.

Mysql version 5.7.29 is in use.

Is there any way that I can speed up the execution of the following, verbatim query?

```
  SELECT id,postcode, ROUND((
                     3959 * acos (
                       cos ( radians(56.007165000) )
                          * cos( radians( latitude ) )
                          * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-3.784005000) )
                          + sin ( radians(56.007165000) )
                          * sin( radians( latitude ) )
                        )
                    ),1) AS distance
              FROM postcodelatlng
              HAVING distance <= 10
              ORDER BY distance
```

So I have updated the original query to add a bound box like this:

```
  SELECT id,postcode, ROUND((
                 3959 * acos (
                   cos ( radians(56.007165000) )
                      * cos( radians( latitude ) )
                      * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-3.784005000) )
                      + sin ( radians(56.007165000) )
                      * sin( radians( latitude ) )
                    )
                ),1) AS distance
          FROM postcodelatlng
           WHERE latitude BETWEEN 56.007165000 - 10/69.172
                              AND 56.007165000 + 10/69.172
              AND longitude BETWEEN -3.784005000 - 10/69.172 / COS(RADIANS(56.007165000))
                                AND -3.784005000 + 10/69.172 / COS(RADIANS(56.007165000))
          HAVING distance <= 10
          ORDER BY distance


   --
 -- Table structure for table `postcodelatlng`
 --
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `postcodelatlng` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `postcode` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
   `latitude` decimal(12,9) NOT NULL,
   `longitude` decimal(12,9) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
   --
 -- Indexes for table `postcodelatlng`
  --
 ALTER TABLE `postcodelatlng`
   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   ADD KEY `postcode` (`postcode`),
   ADD KEY `latitude` (`latitude`,`longitude`),
   ADD KEY `longitude` (`longitude`,`latitude`) USING BTREE;
```

here is and example of the data:

```
INSERT INTO postcodelatitudelongitude (postcode,latitude,longitude) VALUES ('AB10', '57.13514','-2.11731');
INSERT INTO postcodelatitudelongitude (postcode,latitude,longitude) VALUES ('AB11', '57.13875','-2.09089');
INSERT INTO postcodelatitudelongitude (postcode,latitude,longitude) VALUES ('AB12', '57.10100','-2.11060');
INSERT INTO postcodelatitudelongitude (postcode,latitude,longitude) VALUES ('AB13', '57.10801','-2.23776');
```

dbfiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mi4D1937k9WpeM3ubMBLjw/0

Comment: The question about the speed-up of the query is hard to answer as you don't provide the data that the query is bound to. This might be due to a limitation of licensing rights, but please understand that unless the scenario re-producible, you will likely not get appropriate answers to your question.

Comment: The data is available for free here: https://www.freemaptools.com/download-uk-postcode-lat-lng.htm    ukpostcodesmysql.zip

Comment: All I am trying to do is optimize the query

Comment: sounds great, why not create a dbfiddle out of it to demonstrate your issue? It should be possible to easily link it (at least). (that you would like to optmize the query I'd say is already prominent in the question, if you allow me the comment)

Comment: will dbfiddle allow a db of that size? 234MB

Comment: try it and then tell if you were able to crash it ;)  - I would expect if the upload is okay from your end that dbfiddle will either allow it or not, and therefore consider it safe to  try it out. I've never done it thought.

Comment: The query, as it stands, must check every row.  That is the costly part.

Comment: @hakre - "find nearest" is a common problem.  It is easy to specify; hard to solve efficiently.

Answer (score 4):

Since 5.7 (.9; GA: 2015-10-21) there is the [`ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere) for distance available (also: [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/st_distance_sphere/)).

Example:

```
SELECT 
       id,postcode,
            ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(POINT(-3.784005000, 56.007165000), POINT(longitude, latitude)) / 1000 AS distance
              FROM postcodelatlng
              #HAVING distance <= 10
              ORDER BY distance
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=780b4d43b9994fdc68e8506f4687f730)

---

Alternatively, switch to a *geometry* data type and use [a ***spacial*** index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-spatial-indexes.html).

So as the question was asked for mile

```
SELECT 
       id,postcode,
            ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(POINT(-3.784005000, 56.007165000), POINT(longitude, latitude)) / 1609.344 AS distance
              FROM postcodelatlng
              HAVING distance <= 10
              ORDER BY distance
```

Comment: When i run this on my machine i get: Incorrect arguments to st_distance_sphere

Comment: then you copied the code wrong as you see it works in dbfiddle

Comment: I see it works in the fiddle but it doesn't on my machine. Copied and pasted exactly

Comment: It maybe that some rows have invalid latitude/longitude coordinates in the database which causes this error. But i cant go through and fix them.

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.29, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: There are some records in the db that have '99.999999','0.000000' this seems to be the cause of the st_distance_sphere error

Comment: Although i can get to run the distances are massively inflated with this query is it in miles or KM?

Comment: That still requires checking every row.

Comment: @user794846 99 sounds like a latitude being used to say "unknown".  Suggest you replace such with NULL and skip those rows when searching.

Comment: @user794846 - There is no comma, and the entire `'POINT(11 22)'` must be quoted.

Comment: @user794846 - Change `1000` to the number of meters in a mile.

Comment: @nbk Why Dividing by 1000? It giving in meters already as it mentioned in link you posted

Comment: he wanted Miles so the correct  answer would be do divide the distance in meters with 1609.344, but here was the question how to do it and i shouwed how it works, but i added a Version for miles

Answer (score 1):

The first step in optimizing a "find nearest" with lat/lng is to include a "bounding box" in the `WHERE` clause.

I discuss 5 "find nearest" algorithms in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql  Your code is the first, namely brute force.  With 1.8M rows, any of the others will be at least a few orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: I have updated the original question to add in a bounding box like outlined in the second example in your notes. I added the INDEX(lat, lng)
    INDEX(lng, lat) etc and it does seem faster. Is it correct what i have done?

Comment: @user794846 - That looks good.  (With 4 rows, the speedup won't be noticeable; with 1.8M, it should be obvious.)

Comment: Yes the above query takes 0.1249 seconds. as opposed to 4.6 seconds!