# Given a user's lat lng, how to find the nearest lat lng from a database of thousands of lat lng?

Tags: mysql, geometry, geolocation, geospatial, latitude-longitude

I have data of locations of thousands of sensors in MySQL. I want to identify the sensor closest to the user's location and show that specific sensor's data. All the location data is available as lat lng.

I understand that one approach can be to find displacements between the origin and all the sensors using Haversine formula and select the one with the shortest distance. The problem here is that there are tens of thousands of sensors.

Any suggestions/leads?

Comment: it  is nit the fastest way but use https://stackoverflow.com/a/68416398/5193536 to get the disance and define the maximum distance you want, after that you all sensors and can select the timeline you want  to see

Comment: @nbk thanks for the response. Here's the caveat, I cannot apply the condition of maximum or minimum distance since the user can be 0.5 or 50 kilometers away. The nearest sensor has to be identified either way.

Is there is way to identify the nearest location from origin just using the coordinates that you are aware of?

Comment: as you see in the example you get diostance as result and then apply a distance between 0.5 and 50, you must of course check the units i thing the one uses kilometers, but you figure it out when you look in google maps and check the distance. and they are found. but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60065116/mysql-request-for-combining-and-searching-in-2-tables/60067302#60067302 for a working example and adept it

Answer (score 1):

Spatial index allows efficient query of points within any specific distance. The problem of course is one might not know the search radius needed in specific case. Unfortunately, a large radius causes inefficient queries, and a small radius might result in no match at all.

A possible solution is to search with increasing radius, until the search returns some results, and then find the closest result among those.

This article describes this solution for BigQuery, would require some adaptation for MySQL script dialect:
https://mentin.medium.com/nearest-neighbor-using-bq-scripting-373241f5b2f5

Answer (score 1):

Not the MySQL answer you are looking for but Postgresql's popular PostGIS extension has an [inbuilt K Nearest Neighbor operator class)](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/knn.html). Also, see its [documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html). It works great!

Also, I am aware of this [Go library](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/paulmach/orb/quadtree#section-readme) that allows you to do KNN in memory after building a Quadtree with your sensor locations.

Answer (score 1):

For only thousands, a simple bounding box with two 2-column indexes may be fast enough.

For better speed, see `SPATIAL` indexing.

For details on those two solutions, plus two faster ones, see [*Find Nearest*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql)