# Mysql returns 0 rows for distance calculation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where i have added 2 nearby locations which i calculated from google map.

Now my query is to get that nearby location with this query

```
SELECT ppl.Title,

     FLOOR((6971 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((30.027055299999997 - abs(ppl.Latitude)) *
     pi()/180 / 2), 2) + COS(37 * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(ppl.Latitude) * pi()/180) *
     POWER(SIN((-95.4558895 - ppl.Longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )))*1000)
     as distance 
     
     from `mobile_ppl` as ppl  where  ppl.Longitude=-95.4558895 AND ppl.Latitude=30.027055299999997 AND ppl.user_id!=4 GROUP BY ppl.user_id HAVING distance <500
```

second code

```
SELECT 
    ppl.Title,
    ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(POINT(- 95.4558101, 30.026540100000002),
            POINT(ppl.Longitude, ppl.Latitude)) / 1000 AS distance
FROM
    `mobile_ppl` AS ppl
WHERE
    ppl.Longitude = - 95.4558895
        AND ppl.Latitude = 30.027055299999997
        AND ppl.user_id != 4
GROUP BY ppl.user_id
HAVING distance < 500
```

These are the coordinates

Location 1

Latitude: **30.027055299999997**

Longitude: **-95.4558895**

Location 2

Latitude:   **30.026540100000002**

Longitude:**-95.4558101**

[image]

After trying for several hours i still can't figure out why this is not working. Please help me out.

Check Fiddle : [Fiddle SQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2f1e243416bf02bd38fdd20b003aad8f)

Comment: you know that there a more modern ways to calculate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68416319/how-optimize-this-distance-query-based-on-latitude-and-longitude-in-mysql/68416398#68416398

Comment: @nbk Thanks alot but its we changed the number often as required. The same distance formula is working in other API's. I still not able to figure out what's wrong in my query. Btw the link you mentioned has simple way but i am really not sure about it's accuracy.

Comment: don't post images form your data, to debug we need text, see the fiddle in the link change it and please also don't post code in comments

Comment: @nbk done with fiddle please check

Comment: seems like not your immediate problem, but don't store values as floating point or double precision and expect equality checks to work.  from your data, I suggest decimal(10,7) (which would store those latitudes as 30.0270553 and 30.0265401)

Comment: @androidXP see the changed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the modern version of distance, you get an result.

But i don't know why you are grouping it

so with your data

Your problem is basically only the decimal column as it cuts out all digits after the 9 th and so the comparison will fail always,

You have two possibilies

Save the data as varchar or double like in the example. or use spatial datatype

where xyou save the point

> ```
>  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mobile_ppl` (
>    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>    `user_Id` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
>    `Title` varchar(28) NOT NULL,
>    `latitude` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
>    `longitude` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
>    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
>  ) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mobile_ppl (user_Id,Title,longitude,latitude) VALUES ('10','Temp Location 1', '-95.4558895','30.027055299999997');
> INSERT INTO mobile_ppl (user_Id,Title,longitude,latitude) VALUES ('4','Temp Location 2' ,'-95.4558101','30.026540100000002');
> INSERT INTO mobile_ppl (user_Id,Title,longitude,latitude) VALUES ('3','Temp Location 3' ,'57.10100','-2.11060');
> INSERT INTO mobile_ppl (user_Id,Title,longitude,latitude) VALUES ('7','Temp Location 4' ,'57.10801','-2.23776');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     ppl.Title,
>     ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(POINT(- 95.4558101, 30.026540100000002),
>             POINT(ppl.Longitude, ppl.Latitude)) / 1000 AS distance
> FROM
>     `mobile_ppl` AS ppl
> #WHERE
> #    ppl.Longitude = - 95.4558895
> #        AND 
> #ppl.Latitude = 30.027055299999997
> #        AND ppl.user_id != 4
>
> #HAVING distance < 500
> ```
>
> ```
> Title           |            distance
> :-------------- | ------------------:
> Temp Location 1 | 0.05779522176337853
> Temp Location 2 |                   0
> Temp Location 3 |  15771.686509015213
> Temp Location 4 |  15782.978003441733
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     ppl.Title,
>     ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(POINT(- 95.4558101, 30.026540100000002),
>             POINT(ppl.Longitude, ppl.Latitude)) / 1000 AS distance
> FROM
>     `mobile_ppl` AS ppl
> WHERE
>     ppl.Longitude = - 95.4558895
>         AND 
> ppl.Latitude = 30.027055299999997
>         AND ppl.user_id != 4
>
> HAVING distance < 500
> ```

> ```
> Title           |            distance
> :-------------- | ------------------:
> Temp Location 1 | 0.05779522176337853
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e503bcb66e06b0e3b1d1804fc2997e68)*

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mobile_ppl (user_id int,title varchar(100) , Latitude varchar(100), Longitude varchar(100) )
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mobile_ppl VALUES (
> 2,'Location 1',
>
> '30.027055299999997',
>
>  '-95.4558895'),
>
> (2, 'Location 2',
>
> '30.026540100000002',
>
> '-95.4558101')
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     ppl.Title,
>     ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(POINT(- 95.4558101, 30.026540100000002),
>             POINT(ppl.Longitude, ppl.Latitude)) / 1000 AS distance
> FROM
>     `mobile_ppl` AS ppl
> WHERE
>     ppl.Longitude = - 95.4558895
>         AND ppl.Latitude = 30.027055299999997
>         AND ppl.user_id != 4
>
> HAVING distance < 500
> ```

> ```
> Title      |            distance
> :--------- | ------------------:
> Location 1 | 0.05779522176337853
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3abf2dd508a629bf855f69289e1992ce)*

Comment: i used your fiddle see the first example  and corrected the many errors filed langth table name and the group by that not makes any sense , change the columns for latitude qaned longitude in double and then it should work,

Comment: Thanks. My fiddle is working too but when i run same command in phpmyadmin it shows 0 result.  Latitude and Longitude is in Varchar 250. Any idea why i am getting 0 rows

Comment: try double as type also see the fiddle i posted, the first shows that i removed the where clause,to check and then add one where at the time to check which caused the problem

Comment: When i run query in `phpmyadmin` without where clause then its working. Why its not working with where latitude = 213 AND longitude = 2312. After all it's a filter which needs to check .

Comment: add the columns that are not working to the fiddle and i can take a look. Have you installed the latest updates?

Comment: I fix this by your solution in comments. It was not working because i am checking lati == xxxx and longi == xxxx. It will never give me result because i am looking if these values are equals to value in DB.  Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: yes the querys looks for exact matches with the same latitude and longitude, usually you don't have these as you are only intrerested in the distance, but i don't know eatly wjat you are looking for, so i copied your query. all  WHERE clause reduce the number of rows that are displayed#