# Multiple Tables Left Join and Aggregates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have a problem with my join, every time a row from the second table has more than 1 row

For this example:

```
tblUsers   tblUsersCars   tblUsersHouses
---------  -------------  ------------------
id         idCar          idHouse          
name       qty            qty
lastName   type           type
           idUsers        idUsers 
--------------------------------------------

        tblUsers       |    tblUsersCars   |     tblUsersHouses     |
-----------------------|-------------------|------------------------|
1, Matt, Groening      |   7, 1, red, 1    |   15, 1, "2 Floors", 1 |
2, Steve, Segal        |   8, 2, blue, 1   |                        |
3, Scarlett, Johanson  |                   |                        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

With these tables, every time I run my query, I expect this result:

```
id | name | lastName | cars | houses |
---+------+----------+------+--------+
1  | Matt | Groening |   3  |   1    |
```

But instead I get this result:

```
id | name | lastName | cars | houses |
---+------+----------+------+--------+
1  | Matt | Groening |   3  |   2    |
```

So what I notice is that the last column (houses) will duplicate as many times as rows are in the the column (cars) so in this example in `tblUsersCars` there are 2 rows and only 1 row in `tblUsersHouses`, but in the result the row in `tblUsersHouses` is duplicating once more to match `tblUsersCars` number of rows.

Is there any way I can fix this query no matter how many rows are in each table? I just want the sum of qty from both tables in my final query.

This is the query I'm trying to run:

```
SELECT 
    tblUsers.id, tblUsers.name, tblUsers.lastName,
    COALESCE(SUM(tblUsersCars.qty), 0) AS 'cars',
    COALESCE(SUM(tblUserHouses.qty), 0) AS 'houses'
FROM 
    tblUsers
LEFT JOIN 
    tblUsersCars ON tblUsersCars.idUsers = tblUsers.id
LEFT JOIN 
    tblUserHouses ON tblUserHouses.idUsers = tblUsers.id
WHERE
    tblUsers.id = 1
GROUP BY
    tblUsers.id, tblUsers.name, tblUsers.lastName
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

**I solved it using @nenad aswer**

Comment: that is a horrible way to display data,

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @nbk can you elaborate on what can i improve?

Comment: your problem is that the tbusershouses are join with every car and that is twice there, so the number doubles and so on , just sums before joining

Comment: @Code_Geass look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71729043/5193536  this way we are able to help you better

Comment: The results returned are correct given the input data and query. You should look at the full results returned by the query. Remove the `GROUP BY`, then remove the entire `SELECT` and change to `SELECT *`. This will probably give you a better idea of what your code is doing and why it's not matching up with your expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make aggregated results for cars and houses per user-id, before you join across the tables. The issue in your current approach is that you have two cars, each one joined with the one house. So house entry exists for both cars. Simplified:

| UserId | CarId | HouseId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |

So, fix can be written in many ways, but using common-table-expression is for me most readable:

```sql
;WITH CarsCTE AS
(
    SELECT idUsers, SUM(qty) as cars
    FROM tblUsersCars
    GROUP BY idUsers
),
HousesCTE AS
(
    SELECT idUsers, SUM(qty) as houses
    FROM tblUsersHouses
    GROUP BY idUsers
)
SELECT id, name, lastName, cars, houses
FROM tblUsers AS u
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CarsCTE ON CarsCTE.idUsers = u.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN HousesCTE ON HousesCTE.idUsers = u.id
WHERE id = 1
```