# How can geo query with JOINs be optimized to be faster and more efficient?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm currently using PlanetScale for database hosting and I'm trying to monitor my queries' performance so that it doesn't affect pricing too much and I see that my recently added SQL query is hitting the database pretty hard and it takes ~26ms to execute. So the question is, why? And how can I optimize the query to execute faster and take less resources?

All I'm doing here is finding closest cities to desired city that have data about population and has airport entity connected to it:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT neighbour.*,
(
  6371 *
  acos(cos(radians(main.latitude)) *
  cos(radians(neighbour.latitude)) *
  cos(radians(neighbour.longitude) -
  radians(main.longitude)) +
  sin(radians(main.latitude)) *
  sin(radians(neighbour.latitude)))
) AS distance
FROM flaut.City neighbour
JOIN flaut.City main ON neighbour.code <> main.code
JOIN flaut.Airport airport ON neighbour.code = airport.cityCode
WHERE main.code = 'MOW'
AND neighbour.population IS NOT NULL
HAVING distance < 800
ORDER BY distance;
```

According to PlanetScale this query is the heaviest on DB engine among all the other queries I have

[image]

Although `DESCRIBE` doesn't appear to indicate what's wrong, it doesn't read that much from the database

[image]

Comment: Why not use modern functions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68416319/how-optimize-this-distance-query-based-on-latitude-and-longitude-in-mysql/68416398#68416398   also don't upload images see  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing a cross join for every house to every other house and then performing this calculation on them.  Only after the calculation do you filter by the nearest ones.

You need to find a way to filter BEFORE the calculation.  This can be done.  If you think about a distance you calculate given two points in lat and long by finding the distance with complicated math..  But you know if the distance between the two lat or the two long are greater than some amount the distance between the 2D distance must be greater.  If you filter on that before the calculation (if you have an index on them this will be much faster.)

So it would look something this (where x is the lag/long distance you want to be shorter than):

```
 JOIN flaut.City main ON neighbour.code <> main.code
                     AND neighbour.latitude - main.latitude < x
                     AND neighbour.longitude - mail.longitude < x
```

Answer (score 0):

(I assume that `WHERE main.code = 'MOW'` identifies one specific lat/lng.)

To find the city nearest to one specific lat/lng:

- With no index -- must read and test distance to every city
- With a "bounding box" and `INDEX(lat, lng)` and `INDEX(lng, lat)` -- better speed
- With a bounding box and either a SPATIAL index or a certain usage of Partitioning or a Z-order index -- even better speed

All of this is discussed in [*Find Nearest*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my issue using the idea from [Hogan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76574772/4704823) here by splitting single SQL query into two separate ones. Instead of JOINing cities on cities, first I got the original city's lat/long and then I reused those in the following query:

```sql
SELECT city.*, ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(POINT(37.617634, 55.755787), POINT(city.longitude, city.latitude)) / 1000 AS distance
FROM flaut.City city
JOIN flaut.Airport airport
ON airport.cityCode = city.code
AND airport.longitude BETWEEN 33.617634 AND 41.617634
AND airport.latitude BETWEEN 51.755787 AND 59.755787
WHERE city.code <> 'MOW'
AND city.population IS NOT NULL
HAVING distance < 800
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 10;
```

Where

- `37.617634, 55.755787` are coordinates of the original city I'm searching neighbours for
- `33.617634 AND 41.617634` are longitude offsets (longitude - 5, longitude + 5)
- `51.755787 AND 59.755787` are latitude offsets (latitude - 5, latitude + 5)

The offset value of `5` is just a random offset turned out to be acceptable enough for this query to work. One might use 7.2 since 111.3km * 7.2 ~ 800km distance matches the original distance criteria.

Finally I use those coord offsets to only JOIN necessary airports instead of JOINing an entire table dataset. In total it gave the best performance/time ratio and my database usage returned to somewhat normal.

[image]

**I will mark [Hogan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76574772/4704823) as accepted** since it served the initial ground for my own SQL query which I will leave here as an example for the reference.